# Как создаются игры под Windows

Tags: windows, разработка-игр

На каком языке программирования под windows создают такие игры как Паук Сапер и т.д и где взять хорошие книги и компилятор (с поддержкой кирилицы)

Comment: Язык можете использовать любой...<br>
Я бы посоветовал учить java

Comment: @Zowie Java для геймдева? Бррр, чур меня...

Comment: @DaemonHK до сих пор живёте в 90-х? https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx. Нотч тоже бы поспорил.

Comment: @Suvitruf угу, именно оттуда до сих пор аукается тормознутость явы во всяких апплетах, Intellij IDEA и прочем

Comment: @DaemonHK ну, если у вас PC прямиком из 90-х, то да. С другой стороны, Visual Studio в разы тормознутей, но не на Java.

Comment: @Suvitruf и? сейчас шторм даже на i5 порой тормозит жутко, я конечно не знаю всех прелестей Java, но по мне так уж очень прожорливый язык, хотя холиварить можно долго

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DX C++ Горнаков, Станислав

VC++ MFC и API функции Давыдов, Владимир

Очень хорошие книги у шилда

ну это так с ходу, сам только начал осваивать... очень доходчиво изложен материал.

Видел еще пару книг, но никак не могу найти электронный вариант..

ЗЫ: Сколько людей столько и мнений, начинаешь читать книгу... и понимаешь, или ты видишь фигу или ты всё схватываешь на лету... так что авторов и книги подберешь постепенно сам)

компилятор любой, dev-c++, visual studio, C++ builder ссылки на скачивание легко найти в инете)

Answer (score 0):

Писать программы можно на любой языке программирования.
осмелюсь предложить начните с изучения Delphi он более легок для восприятия нежели С++

Answer (score 0):

Современные средства и языки для разработки игр:

- C++
- C
- Delphi
- Java
- Flash
- OpenGL (Открытая графическая библиотека, графическое API)
- PhysX (Физический движок компании nVidia)
- DirectX (Набор API , наиболее широко используется при написании компьютерных игр)

ну и GameMaker =))))))) На нём наверно MicroSoft и писали Сапера и Паука :DDD (САРКАЗМ!)